# Install several versions of the rpm packet

Tags: fedora, yum, package-management, rpm

I need to use python2.5. But my system (FC11) have python 2.6 only. How can I install and use several versions of python with yum or rpm? Or maybe I need to compile python 2.6 from sources?

Comment: In the title, packet should be package.

Answer (score 1):

Does FC11 not ship with Python 2.5 at all, or is it just not installed by default?

On an Ubuntu 9.04 machine I have both available:

```
$ apt-cache search python | egrep '^python2.6 |^python2.5 '
python2.5 - An interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.5)
python2.6 - An interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.6)
```

But only 2.6 is currently installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | egrep 'python2.6 |python2.5 '
ii  libpython2.6    2.6.2-0ubuntu1    Shared Python runtime library (version 2.6)
ii  python2.6       2.6.2-0ubuntu1    An interactive high-level object-oriented la
```

I can still install 2.5 if I want to, with:

```
$ sudo aptitude install python2.5
```

Perhaps you can still install 2.5 using `yum` even though it's not installed by default?

My apologies for not answering your question directly, but I do not have access to a Fedora machine. I hope this can help still.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your quickest route to having Python 2.5 available alongside 2.6 on FC11 might be to compile from source, making sure to specify a --prefix so as not to interfere with the system installed 2.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple versions installed, but you would need RPM's that hold this into account. For example, but installing all files in completely different paths. That is probably what Ubuntu does, but I'm not sure: it's also possible Python 2.5 and 2.6 on Ubuntu are mutually exclusive. In that case installing another version than the default might be a bad idea, since a lot of system management software today is written in Python. Yum is, just to name one. I think Ubiquity is, too.

If you have enough time, I suggest you build it yourself. Consider building RPM's instead of running

```
make install
```

though... It's not hard to make a proper RPM and it'll benefit you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[RPM Fusion](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/11/Everything/source/SRPMS/repoview/compat-python24.html) seems to provide python 2.4.
It's called compat-python24 and the version is 2.4.5

You could try to update to python 2.5 using their SRPMS

Answer (score 0):

With minimal change to the spec file, the Fedora 10 RPM supports being rebuilt in a way that installs in Fedora 11.  You can download a src RPM with the patched spec file or a i586 binary rpm here:

[Fedora 11 Python 2.5 RPMs](http://wtanaka.com/linux/f11#python25)